# Failed yum update rendered CentOS 7 install almost useless – where to look for root cause?

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, yum

I was doing my regular yum update and it kept failing. Following various advice online I finally managed to clear it out and get it happy that there were no outstanding tasks and no updates available. Then I rebooted. Now the only way I can access the server is via a local console provided by Digital Ocean.

A big part of the problem, I deduce, is that the network service is in a failed state. I've also, in trying to find the problem, ascertained systemd.logind is in a failed state. Even the console is very slow to react and sometimes won't let me log on for many minutes if I reboot the server.

I'm sure it's just down to some missing or corrupted files but my experience thus far is in getting a working system to behave how I want. I'm quite lost on this one!

On the yum issue (the certain cause) I tried yum-complete-transaction multiple times to no avail. It told me to repair the database. To accomplish this I did the following:

```
mv /var/lib/rpm/__db* /tmp/
rpm --rebuilddb
yum clean all
```

I kept getting hangs after that. Further reading suggested a memory issue, so I shut down my web and database servers and tried the above repair again. Then running a yum-complete-transaction completed normally! It did give me this warning:

```
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
```

Having got successful completion, I ran yum update once more and it reported nothing needed updating. Success! I thought...

I rebooted the server, after which it got into its severely degraded state.

I hadn't got around to making a server-level backup, though I do have backups of all my web and database content. That will mean a rebuild if I can't resolve the issue in situ.

Any pointers to which logs to check for the root cause of the failures would be VERY MUCH appreciated. I do have a recovery ISO console operating which is helping me get some up-to-the-minute backups and lets me look at logs more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually discovered after booting to Recovery ISO and running fsck – which reported NO errors – that the subsequent reboot was normal. All up and running. Phew! Server level backups are now ON.